# Differentiating between embedded NUL and NUL-terminator

Tags: c, pointers, nul

I have a `const char*` pointing to data in hex format, I need to find the length of the data for that I am checking for `NUL`-terminator but when `\x00` comes up it detects it as `NUL`-terminator returning incorrect length.
How can I get around that?

```
const char* orig = "\x09\x00\x04\x00\x02\x00\x10\x00\x42\x00\x02\x00\x01\x80\x0f\x00"
uint64_t get_char_ptr_len(const char *c)
{
    uint64_t len = 0;
    if (*c)
    {
        while (c[len] != '\0') {
            len++;
        }
    }
    return len;
}
```

Comment: You must pass the length of the array to `get_char_ptr_len` as an additional argument. Although that is a tautology, since you already know the length ;)

Comment: You cant. Zero is zero is zero.

Comment: Got it, i'll have to manually get the size and hardcode it

Comment: You could always wrap it in a struct to keep the pointer and size together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\x00` ***is*** the NUL terminator; in facts, `\x00` is just another way to write `\0`.

If you have byte data that contains embedded NULs, you cannot use NUL as a terminator, period; you have to keep both a pointer to the data and the data size, exactly as function that operate on "raw bytes" (such as `memcpy` or `fwrite`) do.

As for literals, make sure you initialize an *array* (and not just take a pointer to it) to be able to retrieve its size using `sizeof`:

```
const char orig[] = "\x09\x00\x04\x00\x02\x00\x10\x00\x42\x00\x02\x00\x01\x80\x0f\x00";
```

Now you can use `sizeof(orig)` to get its size (which will be one longer than the number of explicitly-written characters, as there's the implicit NUL terminator at the end); careful though, as arrays decay to pointer at pretty much every available occasion, in particular when being passed to functions.

Comment: I need to get size of data present with that pointer, NULL terminator cannot be a check can there be a workaround?

Comment: No. If you just have a pointer to binary byte data (i.e. where every byte value is allowed) there's no way to determine its length.

Comment: @AamirShaikh: NUL, not NULL. `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant.

Answer (score 0):

`\x` indicates hexadecimal notation.

Have a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see what \x00 represent.

```
\x00 = NULL // In Hexadecimal notation.
```

`\x00` is just another way to write `\0`.

Try

```
const char orig[] = "\x09\x00\x04\x00\x02\x00\x10\x00\x42\x00\x02\x00\x01\x80\x0f\x00";
```

and

```
len=sizeof(orig)/sizeof(char);
```